# VBA-Excel: Range de uma célula contida en uma variável

Tags: excel-vba

Preciso pegar os conteúdos de células identificadas em uma variável.
É possível?

Código:

```
VTI40 = "J44"
VTF40 = "J47"
VTI39 = "H44"
VTF39 = "H47"

QtdVal = Range("B60").Value

QtdInv = 40 - QtdVal

For i = 40 To QtdInv Step -1
    VTI = "VTI" & i
    VTF = "VTF" & i
    CelI = Range(VTI).Value   -> Aqui o conteúdo da célula "J44"
    CelF = Range(VTF).Value   -> Aqui o conteúdo da célula "J47"
Next i
```

Comment: Sugiro utilizar `.Cells()` neste loop e não Range. Mas faça um [mcve] com os dados da tabela, pois é difícil de visualizar desta forma. Crie em exemplo com dados fictícios.

Comment: Sua pergunta parece ter alguns problemas e sua experiência aqui no Stack Overflow em Português poderá não ser a melhor por causa disso. Queremos que você se dê bem aqui e consiga o que quer, mas para isso precisamos que você faça a sua parte. Veja algumas orientações que vão te ajudar: [Guia de sobrevivência do Stack Overflow em Português](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8045) ([versão curta](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8089/101)). Se a solução for muito simples ainda é possível que alguém o faça nos comentários.

Answer (score 0):

Quer copiar os valores de certas células e colocar numa única variável.

```
valor = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Folha9").Range("A" & 20, "E" & 20)
```

Neste exemplo pego nos valores de A 20 até E 20. A variável "valor" será constituída por 5 valores (o que se encontra em A20, B20 até o E20).
Seria necessário realizar um ciclo para colocar esses valores numa string.